# Doctrine how to write fixtures for self referencing relations

Tags: php, doctrine, entity-relationship, fixtures, doctrine-1.2

I'm having trouble in defining fixtures for self referencing relations in Doctrine 1.2, suppose I use [the code from the manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships%3ajoin-table-associations%3aself-referencing-nest-relations%3aequal-nest-relations), how to write fixtures for that?

I tried with this fixture file

```
User:
  JohnDoe:
    username: "john doe"
  MarkSmith:
    username: "mark smith"
    Friends: [ JohnDoe ]
```

but when I run doctrine load task I obtain this error message:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine_Record::setFriends() must be an instance of Doctrine_Access, none given
```

I would try by passing users in FriendReference fixture, but I don't know how to do that, because FriendReference has not relations explicitly declared so I can not do something like this

```
FriendReference:
  First:
    ???: [ JohnDoe, MarkSmith ]
```

or

```
FriendReference:
  First:
    User1: JohnDoe
    User2: MarkSmith
```

**Update**

Here is the example schema taken from the [manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships%3ajoin-table-associations%3aself-referencing-nest-relations%3aequal-nest-relations)

```
---
# schema.yml

# ...
User:
# ...
  relations:
    # ...
    Friends:
      class: User
      local: user1
      foreign: user2
      refClass: FriendReference
      equal: true

FriendReference:
  columns:
    user1:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    user2:
      type: integer
      primary: true
```

Comment: Could you post your schema YAML file?

Comment: @J0HN sure, I posted the schema. Hope you can help me. It's not urgent, but I still need that and I'd be very happy to solve this issue.

Comment: Well, how do you expect `Users` will load to `Question`? Update fixture sample as well. :)

Comment: @J0HN my initial fixture example was intended for Doctrine manual example. I've added it instead of my actual scheme, because the concept is the same. If I solve the issue for the manual example I can adapt it to my actual schema (which is the same with different names)

Comment: Well, maybe that's stupid, but have you tried adding `Friends` declaration to first `User`?

Comment: @J0HN just tried, with the same error message as above i.e. `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine_Record::setFriends() must be an instance of Doctrine_Access, none given`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution for this issue, I needed to introduce two redundant relations in my schema file. The reference table in the schema become

```
FriendReference:
  columns:
    user1:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    user2:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations: # <-- ADDED RELATIONS
    User1:
      class: User
      local: user1
    User2:
      class: User
      local: user2
```

With this definition I can specify fixtures in this way

```
FriendReference:
  First:
    User1: JohnDoe
    User2: MarkSmith
```

It was so simple...